# Not show data in URL ASP MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a simple register login view profile application in MVC and when i call the action method of view profile i'm searching the user on the basis of his/her name.
Now my problem is username is visible in the url
like this

'http://localhost:23444/Home/EditProfile?**Username=arrow**'

Here arrow is my username.
Now i don't want that any details is shown in url like that
is there any way to do this
I've tried to change my RouteConfig.cs still doesn't work.
Here is my RouteConfig.cs file

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you submit a form, the parameter must appear in the url

Comment: There no way you can hide *Username* from Browser address bar unless you use Session, but this don't sounds good, Well before you pass the username in URL why not encrypt it so you can prevent others from seeing it from address bar/history.

Comment: Just don't put the username in the URL. Get it from the signed in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a search functionality, then this behavior is expected. If you just don't want to display it in URL, change the method of the dorm to **POST**. That should hide it from URL.

In case you have a link to other peoples' profiles, then you should follow @vikas_jagdale's answer. There a unique id is displayed in place of the name.

It would be best if you post the part of the code where you have this URL generated, that will help others to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

You do not suppose to set username as a Id, Kindly follow below steps.

1. Create one unique column in DB with the type of unique identifier (GUID in C#).
2. Generate a new GUID during insert the same into DB with user details.
3. Now fetch the list of users with GUID column.
4. And now during creating a grid set your URL as given below -

   @Url.Action("EditProfile", "Home", new { id = item.guidProp })